# Ĉu ekzistas esperanta "Antibarbarus"?

Tags: style

"Antibarbarus" estis dum la latina tempo verko, kiu montras novaj, malkorektaj vortoj kaj ties korektaj, malnovaj formoj.  Ĉu ekzistas tion ĉi ankaŭ en Esperanto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ekzistas la deklaracio pri [*La bona lingvo*](http://claudepiron.free.fr/livres/bonalingvo.htm) kaj la [retejo](http://bonalingvo.net/index.php/%C4%88efpa%C4%9Do), kiu havas ekz. listojn de simplaj samsignifaj vortoj.

Comment: "La bona lingvo" bedaŭrinde ne taŭgas, ĉar s-ro Prion trovas novaj formoj pli bona, se tio estas uzata pli ofte, kaj diris ekzemple: "La lingvo ja ŝanĝiĝis." (ŝercu tion frazon, se vi volas la kuntekston.); la ligilo ŝajnas bone.